# Custom List- Item Edit

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, permissions, custom-list

I created a custom list,

1. Team - users have "Contribute only without edit & Delete" ,
2. Team - has "Contribute without delete"

But 2 nd team can not edit the list item wise, (I also can not edit items wise) it shows as option enabled but when click on edit Item, content is not appeared to edit, only titled is appeared.

I saw that, there is no edit content in " Default Edit Form", refer the image attached, how to restore previous edit form. [image]

Comment: have you added columns in a content type in your list?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the SharePoint Designer 2013, you can open this site in SharePoint Designer and then navigate to the list. Create a new Edit form and set it as default.

[image]

As for the custom permission level, just create the custom permission level via Site Permissions > Permission Levels > Contribute > Copy Permission Level and then deselect Edit permissions.

I have tested in my SharePoint Online environment and it works as expected.